# vue.js - Conditional rendering after variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render a new element once a boolean (`waiting`) changes to true. However, I've realized that once my code goes down one `v-if` statement, then I can't transition to another `v-if` statement. Since the boolean does not change until the first `v-if` is done, what would be the best way to transition to the second `v-if` once the former is done? I can't add the code to be directly under there since the transition depends on input.

I thought about redirecting to another page, but I would like to keep my variables in one place.

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div class="home" v-if="!secondplayer">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="responsive" src="/static/mask.png" alt="Responsive image" />
        <h1>How well do you understand the lyrics in Hamilton?</h1>
        <br />
        <p>Invite a second player by sending them this link: <u>{{url}}</u>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="play" v-if="secondplayer">
      <div v-if="!waiting">
        <div class="container hamilton--header--text">
          <h1><i>Test your understanding of Hamilton lyrics</i></h1>

          <div class="columns hamilton--inner">
            <div class="column is-half left">
              <p class="title">Player 1</p>
              <p class="subtitle">Score: {{playerdata.one.score}}</p>
            </div>
            <div v-if="secondplayer" class="column is-half right">
              <p class="title">Player 2</p>
              <p class="subtitle">Score: {{playerdata.two.score}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="hamilton--lyrics--text">
            <p>{{question.lyric}}
            </p>
            <div class="hamilton--answers">
              <a v-bind:class="{ 'wronganswer': hasAnswered && !item.correct, 'correctanswer': hasAnswered && item.correct}" @click="checkAnswer(item)" v-for="(item, index) in options">{{item.name}}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="waiting">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Waiting for the other player to finish...</h1>
          <img src="/static/Spinner.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="gameOver" v-if="winMessage">
      <div>
        <div class="container">
          <h1>{{winMessage}}</h1>
          <vue-simple-spinner size="big" message="Loading..."></vue-simple-spinner>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, are you saying that you want the second transition to start only after the first transition has finished?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to transition a second time. However, the second transition is independent of the first transition, so the first is caused by `secondplayer`, while the second is caused by `waiting`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply the transition css:

Example:

```
.fade-enter-active { /* <<transition name>>-<<transition class>> */
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

Look [transition classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes) for more detail.